# MonoTouch Multiple Mapkit CLLocationCoordinate2D with Custom PIN Image

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, mapkit, mkannotation

Hello my main issue is how to use `MKAnnotationView` to set a custom pin image for all my coordinate points.

For reference, I've went ahead and hardcoded values that I will normally be calling down from a json webservice call.
Heres an example of a hardcoded trails:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D[] trail1 = new CLLocationCoordinate2D[]{
new CLLocationCoordinate2D(10.74812, -97.330277),
new CLLocationCoordinate2D(10.74501, -97.350277),
new CLLocationCoordinate2D(10.74912, -97.340277),
};

CLLocationCoordinate2D[] trail2 = new CLLocationCoordinate2D[]{
new CLLocationCoordinate2D(10.84812, -97.331277),
new CLLocationCoordinate2D(10.94501, -97.352277),
new CLLocationCoordinate2D(10.14912, -97.343277),
new CLLocationCoordinate2D(10.12912, -97.313277),    
};

mapview.AddAnnotation (new SampleMapAnnotation (trail1));
```

Right now I am using `MKAnnotation` but realized I need to use the `MKAnnotationView` for custom image pins.

```
public class SampleMapAnnotation : MKAnnotation 
{
string _title;

public SampleMapAnnotation (CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate)
{
Coordinate = coordinate;
_title = "Sample";
}

public override CLLocationCoordinate2D Coordinate { get; set; }

public override string Title
        {
            get {
                return _title;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear if your issue is going **(a)** from the webservice answer and a List<> similar to your hardcoded one (i.e. parsing) or **(b)** going from such a List<> and actually use it with some API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [MapCallout sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/MapCallouts) from Xamarin. This is a C# port from the Objective-C [sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html) by Apple. It will show you how to create image-based annotations and show them on a map.